# Pagination code surpassing maximum execution time

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

So I inherited an PHP application that was last maintained in 2003 or so. I've managed to get it migrated over to a new host with updated mySQL and PHP and have replaced all of the deprecated commands and fixed all the bugs except one.

There's a contact list page that puts a pagination index at the bottom of the results, but it errors out a maximum 30 second timeout. I've tried throwing CPU and memory at it already, but the strange thing is that the results on the old hardware are returned in seconds.

I've checked the mySQL query from the console, results are being returned in 0.00 sec -- there's only 3000 records. The error is occurring during the while loop.

```
$order="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM company where isbroker='0'";
  $order2=mysqli_query($db,$order) or die("2");
  $d=0;
  $f=0;
  $g=1;
  $order3=mysqli_fetch_array($order2, MYSQLI_NUM);
  $prev=$start-20;
  $next=$start+20;
  if($start>=20) {
    $begcode_sql="select companycode,companyname from company where isbroker='0' " .
                 "order by companyname limit 0,1";
    $begcode_handle=mysqli_query($db,$begcode_sql) or die (mysqli_error());
    list($begcode,$begcompname)=mysqli_fetch_array($begcode_handle);
    $begcode=substr($begcompname,0,4);
    print "<td><A title='$begcompname' href='view.php'><font color='white'>First<br />$begcode</font></a></td>";
    print "<td><A href='view.php?start=$prev'><font color='white'><<</font></a>&nbsp;</td>";
  }
  print "<p>Begin pagination code</p"; 
  #script is timing out here... too long to run    
while($f < $order3) {
        if($f % 20 == 0) {
            if($f >= $start-5 * 20 && $d < 10) {
                print "<td align='center'>";
                $begcode_sql="select companycode,companyname from company where isbroker='0' " .
                    "order by companyname limit $f,1";
                $begcode_handle=mysqli_query($db,$begcode_sql) or die (mysqli_error());
                list($begcode,$begcompname)=mysqli_fetch_array($begcode_handle, MYSQLI_NUM);

                if ( $f != $start ) {
                    print "<A title='$begcompname' href='view.php?start=$f'><b><font color='white'>";
                    $islast=0;
                } else {
                    print "<font color='grey'>";
                    $islast=1;
                }
                print $g . "<br />" . substr($begcompname,0,4) . "</font>";
                if ( $f != $start ) {
                    print "</b></a>";
                }
                print "</td>";
                $d++;
            }
            $g++;

        }
        $f++;
    }
```

Comment: Queries in loops are never a good sign. Have you logged all queries into a file, in order to know how many queries are being launched?

Comment: Just 10, and they all finish in less than a second.